# How do I use expect for repeat cases, without a long script?

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I am using expect to run a bash script which ssh's to 5 boxes, runs an aptitude dist-upgrade -d, zips up the packages, then scps them back to the original box.

All the boxes have the same password and all the boxes require an input of "y" to say yes to the dist-upgrade.

My current expect script is long and messy with loads of repeats of the following

```
## Original box
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
## Box sshing to
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "want to continue?"
send "y\n"
```

My question is, how do I "dedupe" this so that where a password is asked for it sends the password, and where a continue prompt is asked for, it sends y.  So that I don't have to get a perfect order of what will come when (sometimes a key check is thrown into the mix where I have to send "yes")

Full script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
## This uses manualpatching.sh, used to zip up a list of the latest Debian packages
spawn ./manualpatching.sh
## BOX1
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "want to continue?"
send "y\n"
## BOX2
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "want to continue?"
send "y\n"
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "connecting"
send "yes\n"
## BOX3
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "want to continue?"
send "y\n"
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
## BOX4
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "want to continue?"
send "y\n"
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
## BOX5
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "want to continue?"
send "y\n"
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
## BOX6
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
expect "want to continue?"
send "y\n"
expect "password"
send "Password\n"
## END
expect eof
```

Comment: Please show your script!

Comment: Ok, I will edit the post now

Comment: It's there, let me know what you think, thanks

Comment: Where do you spawn SSH session in the script? I cannot find any `spawn` in the script. And every box should be having different IP address, so you need to spawn SSH with different IP addresses every time.

Comment: spawn ./manualpatching.sh on the fourth line

Comment: Do this script work?

Comment: Yes, manualpatching.sh has no issues, I only need to have expect input the password, the y, and the yes whenever they come, so that this script has no duplicates.

Comment: Maybe this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342588/expect-inside-while-loop-loops-forever?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: That looks good! thank you, I'll try it

Comment: Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Gaurav for pointing me in the right direction.

I slimmed my script right down using exp_continue, it is now much more clean and versatile:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn ./manualpatching.sh
expect {
      "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)" {
            send "yes\r"
            exp_continue
      }
      "password" {
            send "Password\r"
            exp_continue
      }
      "want to continue?" {
            send "y\r"
            exp_continue
      }
}
```

Comment: I would just add `eof` after the "want to continue" action block.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, what will that do?

Comment: right now, there are no patterns that will break out of that expect loop: all the branches use `exp_continue`. expecting `eof` is just an explicit reminder for you( and anyone else who will maintain this script) that you expect the spawned program to end, and the script can then carry on.